# Add check for local wifi connected constraint on WorkManager in android

Tags: android, constraints, android-workmanager

In my current implementation for worker `Constraints`, I am using the below configuration.

```
 Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true).build()
```

I found that by this `Constraints`, Worker only works if the network has internet connection but i want a constraint that works even if there is no internet and device is connected to wifi.

So what could be a way to add network only constraint, not the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the available options for [`NetworkType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/NetworkType). The main problem here is that on newer OS version, the device requires that a Wi-Fi SSID is connected to internet before using it.

If you've setup the device so that it connects to Wi-Fi even when it has no internet connection, you can test one of the other options (`NetworkType.UNMETERED`).

Comment: `NetworkType.UNMETERED` means a network that is not subject to traffic limits, such as the ones not coming from limited data plans. Not this won't help fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such `Constraint` out of the box, so I would suggest you to do this check manually.

You can just trigger the worker and as a first check do:

```
val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?

            connectivityManager?.activeNetwork?.let { activeNetwork ->
                val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork)
                val connectedToWifi = capabilities?.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            }
```

`NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI` should be what you are looking for (not completely sure though, better double-check all the options).

If `connectedToWifi` is `true` then you can perform your operations, otherwise just end the worker returning a result that better suits your needs (You could return `Success` so all ends here, or `Retry` if you want the worker to automatically retry in a while)

Comment: At the moment, I don't want to add check in worker it self as it will allow worker to be run.

Comment: Well then the other solution would be to perform this check before triggering the worker, outside it.

There is no such deidcated `constraint`, so I don't think there is another way you could achieve this.

Comment: After looking into source code, If found that if I recompile Worker library version 2.0.1 with customizing for setRequiredNetwork inside androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobInfoConverter , then it may help